# Can a python class contain a method to delete itslef?

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, tkinter, del

I am coding a tkinter class for data manipulation. I would like to find a way to delete the object by clicking on a button, exactly like the X button to quit a window.
Here is what my interface looks like:

[image: tkinter interface]

The main window is a class that contains the matplotlib plot and general controls.
Each of the three "widgets" on the right are objects of a class that contains a dataframe from loaded csv file and some specific controls like the choice of x-axis and y-axis variable.

I want the X button to make the widget and all it contains disappear and also make the plot disappear from the master object (I assume this part have to be done manually).
Here is the initialization of the Widget class and the definition of the controls:

```py
class Data_Widget():
    """ This Class creates the main window with the curve plot and general buttons like open files, Clear all, Plot all.
    
    Arguments:
    -master: the parent window, automatically the PlotWindow class
    -data: data loaded into the widget self.data used to plot the curve
    -filepath: the filepath of the loaded data
    -color: color of the curve
    
    methods:
    -create_widget_controls : create the controls (buttons...)
    -set_widget_color : set the color of the associated curve
    -set_x_var and set_y_var : set the x and y var of the plotted curve
    -master_plot : gives the order of plotting the curve to the master class (PlotWindow) (method plot_widget)
    -master_clear_plot : gives the order of clearing the plot to the master class (PlotWindow) (method clear_widget_plots)
    -delete_widget : delete the widget
    -create_exportload_popup : export the data contained in the widget as CSV file.
                Used where widget has been created by selecting data from another widget with PlotWindow multiple selection method
    """
    def __init__(self, master, data = pd.DataFrame(), filepath='Nothing loaded', x_var=None, y_var= None, color="blue"):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        # Create variables for data and plot
        self.widget_id=0                            #id of the widget   
        self.filepath=filepath                      #filepath of the loaded data
        self.data = data                            #dataframe loaded into the widget
        self.selected_data = pd.DataFrame()         #data selected by the user
        self.x_var = x_var                          #x variable of the plotted curve
        self.y_var = y_var                          #y variable of the plotted curve
        self.color = color                          #color of the plotted curve
        self.create_widget_controls()               #create the controls (buttons...)

    def __del__(self):
        print ("Object gets destroyed")

    def create_widget_controls(self):
        self.widget_frame = tk.Frame(self.master.scrollable_widgets_frame)
        self.widget_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=None, expand=False)

        empty_space = tk.Label(self.widget_frame, text="")
        empty_space.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.filename_label = tk.Label(self.widget_frame, text="-------------- " + os.path.basename(self.filepath) + " --------------")
        self.filename_label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.x_label = tk.Label(self.widget_frame, text="X axis variable")
        self.x_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.x_var_dropdown_label = tk.StringVar()
        self.x_var_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.widget_frame, self.x_var_dropdown_label, "")
        self.x_var_dropdown.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.y_label = tk.Label(self.widget_frame, text="Y axis variable")
        self.y_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.y_var_dropdown_label = tk.StringVar()
        self.y_var_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.widget_frame, self.y_var_dropdown_label, "")
        self.y_var_dropdown.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.plot_button = tk.Button(self.widget_frame, text="Plot", command=self.master_plot)
        self.plot_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.widget_frame, text="Clear", command=self.master_clear_plot)
        self.clear_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.color_button = tk.Button(self.widget_frame, text="color", bg=self.color, fg="white", command=self.set_widget_color)
        self.color_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.exportload_button = tk.Button(self.widget_frame, text="Export plotted\ncurve as csv", command=self.create_exportload_popup)
        self.exportload_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.delete_button = tk.Button(self.widget_frame, text="X", command=self.destroy_widget)
        self.delete_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, anchor=tk.NE)


        # Load the widget with the data from given by the load function of PlotWindow()
        self.x_var_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        self.y_var_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for col in self.data.columns:
            self.x_var_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=col, command=lambda var=col: self.set_x_var(var))
            self.y_var_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=col, command=lambda var=col: self.set_y_var(var))

        if self.master.auto_plot.get() == 1:
            self.master_plot()
        
        # self.x_var_dropdown.bind('<<OptionMenuSelect>>', self.plot)
        # self.y_var_dropdown.bind('<<OptionMenuSelect>>', self.plot)
    
    def destroy_widget(self):
        self.widget_frame.destroy()
```

For now the function `destroy_widget` only makes the frame disappear but it's only visual and all the data is still there.
I wrote a `def__del__(self)` that should be used to delete the object from outside but I can't figure how to use it do delete the object from within itself.

Comment: You are entirely misunderstanding what `__del__()` is for.  It does not (and fundamentally *cannot*) cause the object to be deleted, it is called in response to the object actually being deleted (which will happen at some point after you no longer have any references to it anywhere).

Comment: (Strictly speaking, it's called when Python detects that an object is unreachable, not when the object is actually deleted. The object hasn't been deleted yet when `__del__` is called, and it might not be deleted after `__del__` is called if Python isn't sure the object is still unreachable. The point about `__del__` not deleting objects stands, though.)

Comment: What if you inspected the stack, find the variable passed and delete it from the parent context?

Comment: I suppose I could delete the object from the parent class but it would be ugly I think (the button is in the widget object but calls a method of the parent class that then destroys the child object)
Thank you for precising how `__del__()` works I entirely understand now.